# How can I reuse a variable in angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing an application with the technologies shown below. I have a Typescript file called "test.page.ts", inside there is the variable "response: any"; I have to reuse this in another Typescript file called "test2.page.html", calling it that, {{response.name}}. How can I do it? Thank you.

Technologies that I currently use:

```
Ionic 4.10.2
Angular 6
8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
TypeScript
Visual Studio Code
```

test.page.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoadingController, NavController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.scss'],
})
export class TestPage implements OnInit {

  response: any;
  searchTerm: any = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.getData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('URL')
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.response = response;
      console.log(this.response);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a variable, it's an instance property.

Comment: "Reuse" how? Why?

Comment: if you want to re-use the content that you assign doing `this.response = response` you can use a `Subject` or an  `@Input`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thank you! How can i do it?

Comment: @GiuseppeDamis I've posted a simple code that hopefully will let you undestand better the mean of Subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subject to do that. Here's a simple, basic example.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

App.Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isEnglish = true;
  constructor(private service: CommonService){ }

  setLang(){
    this.isEnglish = !this.isEnglish;
    (this.isEnglish) ? this.service.setLang('IT') : this.service.setLang('EN');
  }
}
```

App.component.html

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" (click)="setLang()">Click me to change language</span>
<br><br>
<my-test></my-test>
```

The service

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService{
  private lang$ = new Subject<string>();
  public langEvent = this.lang$.asObservable();

  public setLang(lang){
    this.lang$.next(lang);
  }
}
```

Test.Component.ts (it handles the data received from the subscription)

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit  {
  lang ="default";
  constructor(private service: CommonService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.langEvent
    .subscribe(res => {
      if(!!res){
        this.lang = res;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The html

```
Current language : {{lang}}
```